# Start algorithm step numbering not at 1

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I have part of an algorithm that branches off from another algorithm, so I would like to present the numbering of the steps starting from that number instead of 1. Right now, I have it set up as follows:

```
\begin{algorithm}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE Step 5
    \STATE Step 6
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
```

I've found a few things about how to change line numbering, but couldn't make anything affect the step numbering.

Answer (score 2):

Store the counter and restore it using TeX's `\label`-`\ref` system and the support of [`refcount`](http://ctan.org/pkg/refcount):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic,refcount}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \STATE First step
    \STATE Second step
    \STATE Third step
    \STATE Fourth step \label{alg:last-step}
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\begin{algorithm}
  \begin{algorithmic}[1]
    \setcounterref{ALC@line}{alg:last-step}
    \STATE Fifth step
    \STATE Sixth step
  \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Note that [`algorithmicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx) provides `\algsave` and `\algrestore`, specifically for this purpose.

Comment: Actually it's `ALG@line` not `ALC@line`.

Comment: @foobar: Why do you say that? Have you tried it?

Comment: Yes. I tried with `ALC@line` and it didn't work. Changing it to `ALG@line` it was fine. Not sure, maybe different settings.

Comment: @foobar: The [`algorithms` bundle](//ctan.org/pkg/algorithms) -
 that produces `algorithmic.sty` - has not been updated since 2009. You can search for `ALC@line` in [`algorithms.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithms/algorithms.dtx). My guess is you may have a local (updated/variation) copy of `algorithmic.sty`.